# Google public DNS query over UDP socket

Tags: sockets, dns, udp

Is google public DNS query can be done though UDP socket ?

I followed this https://gist.github.com/vkmc/5563997 but it stucks after sending query and no reply is coming.

I am using 8.8.8.8:53 UDP socket to request

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Responding on UDP port 53 is absolutely required for a DNS name server to work. Google's server definitely does so.

Comment: means client socket port also needs to 53?

Comment: No, for spoofing-resistance reasons the client should send from (and receive on) a high random port number.

Comment: I am using 53 server port of ip 8.8.8.8 and a random client port. So don't getting why it's not working. I can even see DNS request packet in wireshark.